# Get attributes from 2 tables into 1 data source

Tags: list, windows-phone-7, listview, data-binding

I need to get 2 data into 1 data source from 2 tables

Score
user_id
tribe_id
score_mark

Tribe
tribe_id
tribe_name

I need score_mark and tribe_name, however, so far I only able to get score_mark from an Score Object and associated tribe_name from Tribe object

```
    var scores_by_userID_query = from Score score in appDB.Scores where score.user_id.Equals(userID) select score;
    ScoresByUserID = new ObservableCollection<Score>(scores_by_userID_query);

    TribesByScore = new ObservableCollection<Tribe>();
    if(ScoresByUserID != null)
    {
        foreach(Score score in ScoresByUserID)
        {
            var tribes_by_Score_query = from Tribe tribe in appDB.Tribes where tribe.tribe_id.Equals(score.tribe_id) select tribe;
            Tribe tribe_obj = tribes_by_Score_query.FirstOrDefault();
            TribesByScore.Add(tribe_obj);
        }
    }
```

however, this is 2 data source.

I tried to create a new class and load attributes into List , but cant work..How to bind the data into xaml?

Any source to read ?